# Automapper - Map List to object based on value in existing destination

Tags: automapper

I am trying to take an already existing object and use automapper to map another property from a List into it based on a key already in the destination.

Given the following snippet below, Resolve state description will receive only the StateCode, and I need to map the StateName from the list of States into the object.

```
public Location ResolveStateDescription(Location location) 
{
    var stateList = new List<State> {
        new State { StateCode = "CA", StateName = "California" },
        new State { StateCode = "CO", StateName = "Colorado" },
        new State { StateCode = "NV", StateName = "Nevada" },
    };

    var mappedLocation = _mapper.Map(stateList, location);

    return mappedLocation;
}

public class State 
{
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}

public class Location 
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

I have already done so using a Custom Resolver and the Profile below. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this without so much overhead.

```
public class StateMapProfile : Profile 
{
    public StateMapProfile() 
    {
        CreateMap<List<State>, Location>()
            .ForMember (dest => dest.StateName, opt => opt.MapFrom<StateCodeResolver>());
    }
}

public class StateCodeResolver : IValueResolver<IEnumerable<State>, Location, string> 
{
    public string Resolve(IEnumerable<State> source, Location destination, string destMember,
        ResolutionContext context) 
    {
        return source
            .Where(x => x.StateCode.Equals(destination.StateCode))
            .Select(x => x.StateName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Why not construct the object before mapping. Basically `ResolveStateDescription` will receive only the `StateCode`, since you have a list of StateCodes and StateNames, you select the StateName for that StateCode you want from the list and then do your mapping with only a single object of `State` that contains StateCode and StateName

Comment: @Bosco Ah, yea, that would work. I was hoping for a way to just resolve the association between the list and the one record. Your suggestion is more or less like below, correct?

`var mappedLocation = _mapper.Map(stateList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StateCode.Equals(location.StateCode)), location);`

Comment: Yes, you are right. You might also want to check for null if you are using `FirstOrDefault`